# Extra Spacing After "s.t."

Tags: punctuation, white-space

Whenever I type "s.t." in my paper, there is always extra space after it. It also has this wierd thing when I highlight that extra space, it highlight through some random point in my paper. How do I remove that spacing?

I am using Overleaf in case it's a problem specific to that.

Comment: use `.\@` to get a normal space not an end of sentence space

Comment: Hello. You might also consider just writing out "such that" instead - there is a school of thought that says "s.t." is an "abbreviation for the blackboard" - see eg [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/proofs/writingtips.pdf). Of course it doesn't matter a great deal at the end of the day and it's your paper, so if you like "s.t." much better, that's absolutely fine.

Comment: You could also consider using the `\frenchspacing` command in your preamble which gets rid of the extra space after all punctuation marks. TeX/LaTeX is seeing the "." at the end of "s.t." as a period/full stop and inserting the extra space as it would for the end of a sentence. The `\frenchspacing` command eliminates these extra spaces and is also standard in contemporary typesetting (with TeX/LaTeX and some US courts being notable exceptions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Normally after a lower case letter you get an end of sentence space after `.` you can use `.\@` to get a normal space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


aaa s.t. bbb bbb bbb bb


aaa s.t.\@ bbb bbb bbb bb

\end{document}
```